# Proof Transverse Submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^p$ differentiable and $N$ submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^p$. Show that for all $\epsilon>0$ exist $v\in\mathbb{R}^p$ whit $||v||<\epsilon$ such that $f(x)=f(x)+v$ is transverse to $N.$

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know the [transversality theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversality_theorem)?

Comment: Try using the map $F:M\times{S}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^p$ and define $f_v(x) =F(x, v)=x+v$. This generates a family of mappings $f_v:M\times{S}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^p$ and aplply transversality theorem.

Comment: @jimbo: Yes, you tried the right thing. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: $S=\mathbb{R}^p$

Answer (score 1):

The comments provide the proof already, but since I don't think this is a homework problem (a standard proof can be found in Guillemin & Pollack), I'll just spell everything out.

Define a map $F: M\times \mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}^p$ by $F(x,v) = f(x) + v$.  One easily checks that this is smooth, and moreover, at any $(x,v)\in M\times \mathbb{R}^p$ one computes that the differential is:
$$[dF_{(x,v)}] =\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\ & \ & \ \\
\ & df_x & \\\
\ & \ & \ \\
\end{bmatrix}
&
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \ & 0 \\
\ & \ddots & \\\
0 & \ & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So, the map $F$ is submersion at every point, which implies that $F$ is transversal to $N$.  Now, applying the transversality theorem, one concludes that for almost all $v_0\in \mathbb{R}^p$, the map $f_{v_0}(x) := F(x, v_0)$ is transversal to $N$.  In particular, since any open ball around the origin $B_\epsilon(0)$ has a positive measure, there exists $v\in B_\epsilon(0)$ such that $f_{v_0}$ is transversal to $N$, as desired.